# Passing parameters to a bash function in bashrc

Tags: bash, git

I have the code below in my .bashrc file,

```
function gitex() {
  ssh-agent bash -c "ssh-add ~/.ssh/xxx; git $1";
}
```

If I try the command `gitex status`,

I keep getting "bash: syntax error near unexpected token `status'

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: How are you "trying" gitex command?

Comment: Do `set -x; gitex status; set +x` and post (copy-and-paste) what happens

Comment: The following imitation `function gitex() { ssh-agent bash -c "echo; git $1; echo"; }; gitex status` works for me at the command line.